# Switch between one branch and another TFS 2010 - VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Team Foundation Server switch between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240216/team-foundation-server-switch-between-branches)

I need to know if I can switch between branches. If so, how do I do this.
See I need to start a new branch to implement a new feature in my code but due to the overall quality of the legacy code there's a 100% chance that I will need to fix bugs or things like that...

So my question is: How can I say to VS something like "Ok, save what I've done so far and go back to the production branch" and vice-versa?!?

I was hoping to find some kind of "project-level" (not solution) switch that would allow me to choose in which branch to work like:

- Project Interface: Default
- Project Business: Default
- Project Database: NewBranch
- Project Web-Services: SeparatedNewBranch

Comment: Are you asking how to merge changes between branches or how to open solutions to different branches?

Comment: @BNicoll how to open a solution using a specific branch of one or more projects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each branch will have its own working copy on your file system.  VS will open one or the other, and when you want to sync changes from one branch to another, you use the Merge command, and then Check In on the target branch.

I suggest you check out http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/