# Constant prompt for check out on Visual Studio solution startup

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Each time I'm opening the solution in Visual Studio 2012 (integrated with TFS 2012), it asks for check out particular project file:

[image]

I have the latest version of the sources - no differences if you compare the local version to the remote one.

If I allow to check out this particular file, this is what is changed by VS:

```
--- server
<SccProjectName>%24/NM/NM61/...</SccProjectName>
<SccAuxPath>http://tfs.sth.com:8090/tfs/nm</SccAuxPath>

--- local
<SccProjectName>%24/NM/NM62/...</SccProjectName>  --- branch has been changed
<SccAuxPath>http://tfs2012.sth.com:8080/tfs/nm</SccAuxPath>  --- tfs url has been changed
```

What is the reason of such behavior and how can it be fixed (I don't want to check in this change to source control, and I don't want to have this file constantly checked out) ?

Comment: What changes does it make to the file after it's checked out?

Comment: @Dan Puzey: I've included the changes now.

Comment: Which branch is that project referenced from?  Is it possible that you've ended up referencing a version from the wrong branch?

Comment: @Dan Puzey: Could be, but how is it even possible. I was switching between branches couple of times using this batch script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240216/team-foundation-server-switch-between-branches/16440077#16440077.

Comment: Well, I suspect that branch switching is the source of your problem, though I don't know why.